# why can't i show form after it was hidden?

Tags: jquery

I have a form with a select list on it.  If you pick option 1, the form is hidden using jquery and another form is shown.  When you complete that form, it is removed and the original form is shown.  Problem is that form 1 is not visible when it is unhidden.

```
echo "<div id='NewFormArea'><div>";
echo "<form action='submit.php' method='post' name='form1' id='form1' accept-charset='utf-8'> ...(form fields)... </form>";
```

here is the relevant jquery

```
$.ajax({
   type: 'post',
   url: 'include/forms.php',
   data: {                     
       mode: 'getnewform',
       var1: $("#var1").val(),
       var2: $("#var2").val(),
   },
   success: function (response) {     
       var obj = $.parseJSON(response);

       if(obj.mode == 'Show New Form'){
            $("#form1").hide();
            $("#NewFormArea").html(obj.form);
       }

       setTimeout(function(){ 
            $("#form1").show();
            $("#NewFormArea").remove();
       }, 4000);            
   }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because your NewFormArea `div` is malformed: it does not have a closing `</div>`. This means that `form1` is actually a descendant of  that `div`, and when you execute:

```
$("#NewFormArea").html(obj.form);
```

...you actually destroy and remove `form1` completely. It is gone.

So just fix the `div`.

Comment: Thanks, I've been staring at this for an hour and didn't see that.  Much appreciated.